# How to drag content of document from task pane to word

Tags: drag-and-drop, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I have created a word add-in. In the add-in there is a list of documents available. I just want to implement **drag and drop** functionality in the add-in. like when user drag the document from task pane to word then content of document should be display in the word.
I have checked the documents online but there is nothing about this functionality.

Is drag and drop is possible in the word add-in?

[image: Document Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For directly realizing the drag and drop event, I think we don't provide such an API to detect the drop event in doc. But as a workaround, maybe we can implement a "+" button to insert the content to the selection.

For inserting the content in document, we have such JS API called [Body.insertFileFromBase64()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#word-word-body-insertfilefrombase64-member(1))